# How do I disable TTY switching with alt+arrow-key shortcut?

Tags: server, tty, shortcut-keys

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 (because most programs I use have a cli interface) and whenever I try to use (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left/right arrow key</kbd>) keyboard shortcut, for Weechat, the **tty switches** *instead of the irc channels* I have open. I want to **keep the option to switch ttys** and use just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, etc.  Could someone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Just starting happening to me in 18.04 desktop.

Comment: I'm not sure, but default behavior of 18.04 does exhibit this behavior. I recently installed docker-ce and ran into this problem... I am researching cause now

Answer (score 0):

Through some research I was able to figure out what the problem is. X server is not grabbing the keyboard. 
This is what I had in my /etc/X11/xorg.conf:
       `Section "InputDevice"
     Identifier "Keyboard0"
     Driver "evdev"
     Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
     Option "XkbRules"  "xorg"
     Option "XkbModel"  "pc105"
     Option "XkbLayout" "us,us"
     Option "XkbVariant" "oss,bepo"
     Option "XkbOptions"    "grp:shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
EndSection`

Add `Option "GrabDevice" "True"` to before the "End Section" 
Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
If your xorg.conf does not exist, then just create a new section for keyboard with only the new line in it.